# Is it possible to implement wi-fi direct using java on a windows 7 platform?

Tags: java, windows, wifi

I tried searching for any java apis for implementing wifi direct technology in an application for letting two or more laptops communicate. But all I could find was java Android APis. Is there any other way to implement wi fi direct in desktop computers